# Flutter - System bar colors with SafeArea

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add `SafeArea` widget for the flutter app with colorized system bars but somehow they are always turning black.

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
      SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
        systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        systemNavigationBarColor: kSurfaceColor,
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        statusBarColor: Colors.red, // Note RED here
      ),
    );

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: kWhiteColor,
        appBar: _buildAppBar(context), // Title and Avatar are built here
        body: _buildBody(), // This function just returns blank Container for now
        floatingActionButton: _buildFAB(context),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
      ),
    );
  }
```

This is what I see
[image]

If I wrap `SafeArea` inside a `Container` with `color` property set to white, it works but system bar icons also turn white
[image]

Comment: try to move `SafeArea` to wrap the `body` instead of the entire `Scaffold`

Answer (score 16):

Building on @david-carrilho's answer, I created this simple widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ColoredSafeArea extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Color color;

  const ColoredSafeArea({Key key, @required this.child, this.color})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: color ?? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryVariant,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Then wherever I would use a `SafeArea`, I use my little wrapper widget `ColoredSafeArea`.

```
class MyExampleView extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyExampleView({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ColoredSafeArea(
      child: Center(
        child: Text('Nice color bar'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The reason why this works is because it creates a container behind your content with the specified color, then `SafeArea` simply adds the necessary padding based on the device.

Comment: Thanks. The color works but I can't see the system icons now. How to show them?

Comment: I have the same question like Kakyo. Can some one share lights on it?

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but after reading the documentation I came up with a more complete solution.

My answer considers the following:

1. Don't wrap Scaffolds into SafeAreas;
2. [iOS] paint your Scaffold the right Color;
3. [Android] set the System Bars programmatically.

### 1. Proper use of `SafeArea`

`SafeArea` is a widget that performs a `MediaQuery` to add some proper padding to your application. This should happen inside the `body` of your `Scaffold` application. Something like this will lead to code that won't unexpectedly break later on:

```dart
return Scaffold(
  // ...
  body: SafeArea(                // your SafeArea should stay here
    child: YourWidget(),
  ),
);
```

### 2. iOS Notch

As other answers said already, you just have to paint your Scaffold so that you'll get the color you want. Your Scaffold should include a `backgroundColor` property (and your AppBar too, if you have one).

```dart
return Scaffold(
  // ...
  backgroundColor: yourColor,    // the RED you need
  appBar: AppBar(                // if any
    backgroundColor: yourColor,  // maybe RED here, also
    // a system overlay option is included here, too, see 3.
    // ...
  ),
  body: SafeArea(                // your SafeArea should stay here
    child: YourWidget(),
  ),
);
```

### 3. Android SystemUI

As OP did, you need `SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle()` to address Android-related system bar paints.

However, [the documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setSystemUIOverlayStyle.html) says that this method should be called programmatically whenever a new page / a new route is being popped or pushed, if you have different `Route` colors.

Suppose you have a 2.0 `Router`; then, you would write its `build` method as it follows:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color overlayColor = ... your color ...;
    final systemBarColors = SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: overlayColor,
      statusBarColor: overlayColor,
    );
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(systemBarColors);

    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
      value: systemBarColors,
      child: Navigator(
        key: navigatorKey,
        pages: _stack,
        onPopPage: _onPopPage,
      ),
    );
}
```

This will ensure that every time a new page is popped or pushed, i.e. the `build` method of our `Router` is called, the Android system bar and status bar are properly painted.

Answer (score 4):

```
Container(
   color ...
      ),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: 
            AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
               value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
               child: ...
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In addition to the answer you've provided, please consider providing a brief explanation of why and how this fixes the issue.

Comment: I downvoted this. Don't use this solution, `SafeArea`s should ALWAYS be inside the Scaffold. This leads to having the navigation and the system bars being black for no reason.

Answer (score 3):

Replace your Overlay style with below code it will work

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
  SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(statusBarColor: Colors.white));
```

Comment: underrated, used this with a slight adjustment (Colors.transparent) and it does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

For your case just wrapping `SafeArea()` to the top widget that will be DISPLAYED on the screen(example: your 'Today' text widget) should avoid the black color on system bar.

Full example.

```
Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SafeArea(
              child: Text('Today'),
            ),
            Text('Tomorrow')
          ]
      );
```

This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

set only main class

```
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
          SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
            systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
            systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
            statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
            statusBarColor: HexColor(HexColor.primarycolor), // Note RED here
          ),
        );
```

my Example code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    import 'package:loader_overlay/loader_overlay.dart';
    
    
    import 'HexColor.dart';
    
    class CityListActiviy extends StatefulWidget {
      // Initially password is obscure
      @override
      State<CityListActiviy> createState() => _CityListActiviyState();
    }
    
    class _CityListActiviyState extends State<CityListActiviy> {
      TextEditingController userid_Controller = new TextEditingController();
      bool userid_validate = false;
    
      final String requiredNumber = '123456';
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(
          SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
            systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
            systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
            statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
            statusBarColor: HexColor(HexColor.primarycolor), // Note RED here
          ),
        );
    
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: true,
          home: LoaderOverlay(
            child:SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
                backgroundColor: HexColor(HexColor.gray_activity_background),
                body: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: [
    
                        Stack(
                          children: [
                            Container(
                                height: 60,
                                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: HexColor(HexColor.white),
                                ),
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                child: Text("Select Your Location",
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                      fontFamily: 'montserrat_medium',
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                                    ))),
    
                          ],
                        )
                      ]),
                )),
            )
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```