# flutter SafeArea hides system icons unexpectedly

Tags: flutter, user-interface, mobile, safearea

I'm using `SafeArea` to avoid my display area clashing with the latest phones statusbar and camera notch. I use `Scaffold` without an `AppBar`.

### Problem

Although the display area works as expected, a side-effect happens: the statusbar becomes a single-color region and all system icons include WIFI and battery disappear.

### Attempts

I've tried various tips, including

- [Flutter - System bar colors with SafeArea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55250493/flutter-system-bar-colors-with-safearea)
- [Flutter - How to set status bar color when AppBar not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50501799/flutter-how-to-set-status-bar-color-when-appbar-not-present)

But all they do is set the color. The icons are still missing.

### Question

Is this by design or am I missing any useful properties of `SafeArea`?

Comment: if it disappears completely means you have to change the theme on native, if it disappears in the sense by having same foreground and background you have to change it on flutter like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55209774/flutter-change-status-bar-brightness-to-dark

Comment: @Yadu, I suspect that I'm having the first case. But could you be more specific about "change the theme on native"? Do you mean I should resort to coding in native thru Platform Channel?

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes and this https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status

Answer (score -1):

Try this
If you are using like this

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) { return SafeArea(...); }
```

then try this

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) { return AnnotatedRegion( value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light, child:SafeArea(...);
```